# why mysql will not restart / get affected if ibdata1 file is moved?

Tags: mysql, innodb

On my server two websites are hosted (say abc.com and test.xyz.com)

I was trying to rebuild the DB for test.xyz.com and in the process

1.I dropped the database related to it.
2.stopped the mysql ( /etc/init.d/mysqld stop)
3.moved ibdata1 file (/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1) to /tmp/
4. tried to start the mysql

but it is not getting started and on trying to connect to database using terminal, i am getting `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'`.

I tried to move back ibdata1 file from /tmp/ to /var/lib/mysql but there was already a file ibdata1. Its a wonder but now website is not working since NO DB connection.

Both the sites stopped working now. Please help

and-
/etc/init.d/mysqld status gives - mysqld (pid 31905) is running...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick fix:

- Stop your server
- Delete the newly created ibdata1 file in /var/lib/mysql. This file is created automatically when it doesn't exist. Also note, **it most likely contains the data for all your databases on the server.**
- Copy the ibdata1 from your tmp folder back to /var/lib/mysql
- Start server again

I'll explain later, when I have more time, but I think it might be urgent for you to have that quick fix :)

UPDATE: (From comments) You can't connect, okay, the cause for this could be **anything**. I think the best thing to do (you don't have much to loose anyway) is you simply kill mysql.

Do

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

Then

```
kill -9 <the processnumber of mysql from the previous command>
```

Then do as I said earlier. And never ever simply move ibdata1 again :)

Also I'm voting to close as offtopic. Then it's going to be moved to dba.stackexchange.com which is a partner site that is more dedicated to administrating database servers. You might get better help there.

Comment: even stopping mysql is also getting failed. I looked into error logs and seen that '[wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)]'

Comment: I killed the process and tried to restart the server. But it was neither getting started nor getting stopped. I changed file permissions of mysql directory and then it got started (chmod -R 0777).

Comment: I have another issue as well. I see 2 ibdata1 files. may be one is old back up!!... locations are /root/mysql/ibdata1
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
.. is there any method how to know which ibdata1 is active?

Comment: the file under `/root/mysql` is not part of standard mysql installation. Must be a backup of yours or something. I suggest you ask more questions about this issue on dba.stackexchange.com There questions regarding administration are answered. stackoverflow here is for programming questions. You will get better help there.